# Unable to launch firefox with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: webdriver

I'm starting to build a set of simple automated tests. 
I have:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

On the first line (where I instantiate the WebDriver), I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
```

What have I missed? I know what `NoClassDefFoundError` means - the class can't be found, but I'm not familiar with the class in question here. I have selenium-java-2.45.0 on my buildpath.

Comment: Did you even try searching for that exception? Please put some effort in researching before asking questions here. Goolgles first hit is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function

Answer (score 2):

You also need [selenium-server-standalone-version.jar](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/), because the tests run against a Selenium server.

The test starts the server, then it starts the test, the server starts the browsers and the test communicates over the server to the browsers.

Duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function), this also contains possible other solutions, it describes possible other jars needed.

Instead I would use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) as it downloads all depencies for you, see this blog post to get you started: http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/creating-and-running-a-simple-selenium-webdriver-test/2011-09-15

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the "selenium-server-standalone-version.jar" since your server runs against that. I guess you would have added "selenium-java-version.jar".